# How to set up an Internet Connection in Linux Mint?

Tags: networking, linux-mint

My machine has wired Internet connection with Windows 7 OS. In connection properties I see

```
service name : ispone
obtain IP address automatically
obtain DNS server address automatically
```

How do I step above connection in Linux Mint (16 Cinnamon, installed on USB (16 GB))

What I have tried

```
dhclient
    /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.cof 
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

but nothing works.

Comment: Run `tcpdump -i eth0 -n` in another shell. Execute `dhclient` while `tcpdump` runs and add the `tcpdump` output to your question.

Comment: Why aren't you using NetworkManager to mange your network connections?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of that. In some flavours of Linux Ehternet or Wifi internet connection isn't disabled but you need to enable it from the Network Properties.

Go to the top and find the icon that has Wired or Wifi network connection icon.

Right click and go to Edit Connections

From there Go to the Wired dropdown and locate your eth0

Click on Edit and select Connect Automatically

it will run commands in the background and will get you connected to the internet

Answer (score 0):

OK!
I also have been trying to get tech support from my ISP. Two days ago, the tech person came, and did following:

```
Preferences > Network Connections > Add > 
Choose connection type (Select DSL) > Create > 
DSL (tab) > Username > your username > 
Service (given by ISP) > Password (your password)
```

I was selecting Etherent instead of DSL, which was creating problems.

Thanks to those who tried helping out.

Comment: Which version of Linux Mint do you use? I use 17.2, but there isn't any options called DSL

Answer (score 0):

Using terminal: (go to)

```
> cd /etc/network/ 
> open "interfaces" file with your favorite text editor (vim, vi, whatever)
> comment out everything except "auto lo"
```

This worked for me.